# Show html-tags in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a JSON file with a lot of text on various topics. Now I would like to display it in the app but the text contains html tag like `<i> </i>, <a href="#"> </a>, <b> </b>` etc. I would like to be visible in the text but React Native shows these characters as plain text. I tried with `string.replace ("<i>", [function])` but that doesn't work either. Is there someone who has a suitable solution for me?

this is my current map function:

```
{this.state.selectedData.map((item) =>(
                       <Text style={{width:ScreenWidth}}>{item}{"\n"}{"\n"}</Text>
         
                    ))}
```

I already tried to replace like this:

```
    const B = (props) => <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{props.children}</Text>
{this.state.selectedData.map((item) =>(
                           <Text style={{width:ScreenWidth}}>{item.replace("<i>",<B>}{"\n"}{"\n"}</Text>
             
                        ))}
```

But it is not possible to do that. Does someone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Problem , You will need to install react-native-render-html plugin, that will render html tags for you ,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ScrollView, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import HTML from "react-native-render-html";
import { IGNORED_TAGS, } from 'react-native-render-html/src/HTMLUtils';

const htmlContent = `
    <h1>This HTML snippet is now rendered with native components !</h1>
`;

export default function Demo() {
   const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
// props
    tagsStyles= {
 i: { textAlign: 'center', fontStyle: 'italic', color: 'grey' } 
    }
    classesStyles={
      'last-paragraph': { textAlign: 'right', color: 'teal', fontWeight: '800' }
   }

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <HTML 
       source={{ html: htmlContent }} 
       contentWidth={deviceWidth } 
         // classesStyles={classStyles}
          tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
            contentWidth={deviceWidth}
            imagesMaxWidth={deviceWidth } 
     />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

NOTE: the plugin has issues with rendering table tags

you will need to install additional @native-html/table-plugin and react-native-webview plugin and use it together with react-native-render-html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! When i try this i works but the text does not get visible only the image. Any idea?

Comment: do you have table tags in yours html

Comment: no i used the tutorial text as you published to

Comment: Also you check by giving styles values, with tagStyles (i.e. p,h1) and classStyles (i.e. .class{  } }


   <HTML
                        source={{ html: item.short_content }}
                        ignoredTags={[ ...IGNORED_TAGS, 'nav', 'header','head']}
                        classesStyles={classStyles}
                        tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
                        contentWidth={deviceWidth}
                        imagesMaxWidth={deviceWidth }

Comment: import {Dimensions,ScrollView} from "react-native";
   const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

try providing deviceWidth in this way contentWidth = {deviceWidth}

Comment: make sure it is placed inside ScrollView with style= {flex:1} and contentWidth prop is receiving deviceWidth value

Comment: nope those things does not made it work. Do you know how i change the text color?

Comment: okay i got it working. There was a typo! thanks for you help

Comment: no problem! I have updated my answer also, incase you have table tags in html you will need two additional plugins

Answer (score 0):

Using `WebView` could be another option for you.
https://medium.com/@sumitkumarpradhan96/rendering-raw-html-in-your-react-native-application-6c8463c2b69

```
{this.state.selectedData.map((item) =>(
 <WebView
  style={{width: ScreenWidth}}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  source={{ html: item}}
 />
))}
```

**Update**
You can set the webview height dynamically and here is the solution : https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native

Here is the solution: 1. Define script to send document height to native env after loaded website. 2. Handle onMesssage of webview component and reset Height via state.

```
const webViewScript = `
  setTimeout(function() { 
    window.postMessage(document.documentElement.scrollHeight); 
  }, 500);
  true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
`;


...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      webheight:100,
    }

...

<WebView style={{height: this.state.webheight}}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  source={{uri: "http://<your url>"}}
  onMessage={event => {
    this.setState({webheight: parseInt(event.nativeEvent.data)});
  }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  injectedJavaScript ={webViewScript}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
></WebView>
```