# Replace a-tag (html) with react-native component

Tags: react-native

I have a text that contains html tags. for example a `<a> </a>` tag now I can look it up and edit it. I would like to change this tag by a component. Only I can't do that natively in React with `.replace (`) or the like. is there a way to replace a link in the text with my component?

In the text I look up the a-tag by means of this function:

```
if(item.indexOf('<a') > -1){
            var newItem =  item.substring(
                item.lastIndexOf('href="') + 6, 
                item.lastIndexOf('"')-16
            );

            var itemItalic = <Text style={{color:'red'}} onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('http://plaatsengids.nl'+newItem)}}>{newItem.replace("/",'')}</Text> 
            var replaceLink = item.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, ""); // a try for deleting the a-tag but does only remove the HTML not the text and can't replace with component
           
            var newItemWithLink = <Text>{replaceLink}</Text>;
            return  newItemWithLink
    }
```

Then I put it in the component:

```
 var itemItalic = <Text style={{color:'red'}} onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('http://plaatsengids.nl'+newItem)}}>{newItem.replace("/",'')}</Text>
```

The example string:

```
"Buurtschap 't Heeske valt, ook voor de postadressen, onder het dorp <a href=\"/maasbree\" target=\"_blank\">Maasbree</a>."
```

so I am trying to replace the link to the word `"Maasbree"` with the component.

But how do I get this component in the place in the text where the A-tag was?

Comment: check this answer, you need html-render plugin to show html in react-native
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809716/show-html-tags-in-react-native/65809792#65809792

Comment: thanks for the quick response but i can't use this plugin for my problem. I need to replace some specific things with components.